# inconsistency in Cauchy Integral Formula for matrices?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula, functional-calculus

I noticed that for scalars, Cauchy's integral formula

$$
\oint_{C}dz\frac{f(z)}{z-z_{0}}=2\pi if(z_{0})
$$

requires that $f(z)$ be analytic on and inside the contour $C$ (correct me if I'm wrong).

Now there seems to also be a similar relation that works for matrices, as seen at the top of p. 8 in [Higham](http://www.siam.org/books/ot104/OT104HighamChapter1.pdf):

$$
\oint_{C}dzf(z)\left(zI-A\right)^{-1}=2\pi if(A).
$$

However, this relation requires that $C$ *does* enclose all the eigenvalues of $A$. This is perplexing to me, because on one hand you do *not* want the singularities inside the contour, and on the other, you *do*. Why are the requirements for the scalar and matrix versions the total opposite of each other?

Comment: The eigenvalues of A play the role of $z_0$ what you don't want in either case is a singularity of $f(z)$ inside the contour.

Comment: realized this almost immediately after posting the question; embarrassing...

Comment: Are they really oposites? Cauchy's formula requires that $z_0$ be enclosed by $C $. Indeed, if $A $ is a $1\times1$ matrix, the two are the same.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the tag "functional calculus", because the kind of identity you mention is the tip of a very interesting iceberg... :)  E.g., given a holomorphic functions $f$ and an operator $A$ (on something suitable...), how to make good sense of $f(A)$? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases you have 
$$ \oint_C dz (zI -A)^{-1} = 2\pi i \; I$$
when the contour contains all eigenvalues of $A$. This follows e.g. by letting the contour go to infinity.
On the other hand, if $f$ is entire then
$$ \oint_C dz (f(z)-f(A))(zI -A)^{-1} = 0$$
because the integrand extends analytically. And the result follows.
Now, if $f$ is only analytic on a neighborhood of the domain whose boundary is $C$ then you need a priori to define $f(A)$ first (in terms of evals and eigenprojections). A bit more complicated but the conclusion is the same.